# How to get the grouped product ID from a linked product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a grouped product **product-1** , which has many linked products:

-product-1 (grouped product)

- |__ product-2 (simple or variable product)
- |__ product-3 (simple or
  variable product)

I want to get the ID of product-1 using the ID of product-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can't get the product Id** of a particular grouped product through one of its children product IDs, as each child can be in many different grouped products.

The only data that defines the children products IDS for a grouped product is located in `wp_postmeta` table arround the `meta_key` `_children` as an array of children product IDs.

Now if the children product ID which you want to use to retrieve the parent grouped product ID is only the children of one unique grouped product, you can use the following SQL query embedded in a function:

```
function get_parent_grouped_id( $children_id ){
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
        WHERE meta_key = '_children' AND meta_value LIKE '%$children_id%'");
    // Will only return one product Id or false if there is zero or many
    return sizeof($results) == 1 ? reset($results) : false;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE**

Here below `738` is one of the children products Id. It can also be a dynamic value passed via a variable.

```
$parent_grouped_id = get_parent_grouped_id( 738 );
```

---

**ADDITION - Get all grouped products using a [`WC_Product_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query):**

1. Array of grouped products **Objects**:

   $grouped_products = wc_get_products( array( 'limit' => -1, 'type' => 'grouped' ) );
2. Array of grouped products **IDS** only:

   $ids = wc_get_products( array( 'limit' => -1, 'type' => 'grouped', 'return' => 'ids' ) );

Comment: Thanks for replying, how can I get the list of grouped products using wp_query, I m new in wordpress.

Comment: You are awesome, thats what I was looking for.

Comment: @alitaha Ok I have added an addition to get all grouped products in a WC_Product_Query

Answer (score 1):

I've ellaborated a little bit on [previous correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249366/5491302) by @LoicTheAztec and added some caching to it so to avoid multiple database requests. Wrote this for my project, just sharing it with you - don't be harsh on me I'm newby here. Thanks to @LoicTheAztec for his initial answer.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_parent_grouped_id' ) ) {

function wc_get_parent_grouped_id( $id ){

    global $wpdb;

    $cdata = wp_cache_get( __FUNCTION__, 'woocommerce' );

    if ( ! is_array($cdata) )
        $cdata = array();

    if ( ! isset($cdata[$id]) ) {

        $cdata[$id] = $parent_id = $children = false;

        $qdata = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id, meta_value
                                 FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                                 WHERE meta_key = '_children' 
                                 AND meta_value LIKE '%$id%'");

        if ( is_object($qdata) ) {

            $parent_id = $qdata->post_id;
            $children = $qdata->meta_value;

            if ( is_string($children) )
                $children = unserialize($children);

            if ( is_array($children) && count($children) > 0 )
                foreach ($children as $child_id)
                    $cdata[$child_id] = $parent_id;
        }

        wp_cache_set( __FUNCTION__, apply_filters( __FUNCTION__ . '_filter', $cdata, $id, $parent_id, $children, $qdata ), 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $cdata[$id];
}
```

}